# How to lift regularly, without training

Tags: bodybuilding, training

For the last year, I've been on programs which require 3 non consecutive days. Starting Strength, Stronglifts, AllPros

At the moment my life is so hectic that sometimes I can only make it to the gym once or two a week, and sometime it has to be on consecutive days. Apart from changing my programming on a weekly basis, e.g. sometime a upper / lower split to allow for consecutive days, and sometimes heavy full body , to make up for only two times a week. Is there anything else I should be trying which would work well with the randomness?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best thing I could think of would be to try to regulate your routine by adding in bodyweight exercises when you can at home. If you shower in the morning, do them when you wake up if you can't make it to the gym that day; if at night, do them before dinner. While getting to a gym can be time consuming, these types of exercises can be constant, and help to alleviate the stress of missing a workout.

There are a vast assortment of body weight exercises that would work well here, but the simplest ones are likely push-ups, sit-ups, and squats, to offer ones for an assortment of muscles. Jumping squats could also be an option if body weight squats seem too easy.

Depending on the intensity, you could do these exercises either every day in conjunction with your programs, or just on days when you didn't have time for the gym, as a way of keeping your routine in line.